# Sobolev embedding

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, embeddings

I was trying to understand Sobolev embedding, some results about this topic are not clear to me.
My question is the following:
what are the condition on $p_1 , \alpha_1, p_2 $and $\alpha_2$ for
$W^{p_1,\alpha_1}$ to be embedded in   $W^{p_2,\alpha_2}$?

Answer (score 3):

$\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_1 - \frac{n}{p_1} \geq \alpha_2 - \frac{n}{p_2}$.